# Using URL data in laravel views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

struggling to figure out how to best do what I would normally in simple PHP.

I have the following URL:

```
/viewbuild/2
```

The aim is that viewbuild is the view and 2 is the id of the database row.

Normally It would simply be:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

But cant figure out to do it PROPERLY using laravel.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('viewbuild', function()
{
  return View::make('viewbuild');
});
```

And on my view I have done e.g.:

```
<?php
  $build = Build::find(20);
?>

{{ $build->id }}
```

This correctly searches the builds table for a row with the id of 2 and then displays its id.

What I now want to do is pull the '20' value from the URL.

I have tried:

```
Route::get('/viewbuild/{build_id}', function($build_id = null)
{
  $data = array(
    'build_id' => $build_id,
  );
  return View::make('viewbuild', $data);
});
```

And then on my view:

```
$build = Build::find(build_id);
```

But I get undefined constant errors.

Any help on this?

Comment: Not sure but seems like you have a typo on array passing to view. "build_ud" for build_id

Comment: Yeah noticed that, but fixed it and no luck. Think i am going about it the wrong way. Going to try pass the url to the controller and then make the view

Comment: By the way instead of getting build object in controller and passing object to view would be better practice

Answer (score 0):

Basically i can see two things from quick looking at your code:

1. A typo when setting the array to be passed to the view `build_ud` should be `build_id` i presume
2. You are referencing a constant for the build_id (no `$` sign) in your view instead of the passed variable which is passed to the view. Ie:

> $build = Build::find(build_id);

should be:

> $build = Build::find($build_id);

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have worked out the correct way of doing this and solved many of my next questions. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your route closure should look like this:

```
Route::get('/viewbuild/{build_id?}', function($build_id = null)
{
  // Query the database here instead of inside the view
  $build = Build::find($build_id);

  return View::make('viewbuild', compact('build'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, a question however, the page is being treated a folder. So my css etc is now linking to viewbuild/css/main.css. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure your URLs start with a `/` so they are relative to the root path. So your css link should have `href="/path/to/file.css"` (note the leading `/` there)

Comment: Negative, the viewbuild page is on the same level as say 'about' and on the about page it works fine. But Im thinking because the url is viewbuild/id it thinks that viewbuild is a directory?

Comment: Ignore that, sorted the paths now. Thanks again.